# What is the role and usage of the setup function provided by vue3's Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I need to know the correct usage and the best practice of the `setup` function provided by vue3's Composition API.

I checked in my current project where developers actually use the `setup` function instead of creating the component with the traditional approach.

If it is just a design principle or improvement something then where we should apply these. I read the official [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#arguments) but instead, they didn't explain the concept, they just provided the list of arguments available in this function.

***MyBook.vue***

```
<template>
    <span>Warning:- {{warning}}</span>
    <button @click="warning = !warning">toggle</button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
    props: ['warning'],
    setup(props, context) {
        const warning = ref(props.warning)

        return {
            warning,
        }
    },
}
</script>

<MyBook 
    :warning="true"
/>
```

As you can see above, I can't use the same name of a property to data attribute for a component but in the case of setup, we can do this and update the value. (as property should not change within component).

The Vue devtool is also showing the setup as a different category.

[image]

Comment: did you read the passage before that? The [composition API will be explained here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#setup-component-option)

Comment: I think I miss that. But can you explain this concept in simple words? Why do we need this?

Comment: Because options API is faulty by design and operates on synthetic `this` that isn't really class instance but some loosely determined object. Besides being quirky, this causes unsolvable problems for proper use with Typescript. Composition API was heavily borrowed from React where it proved its usefulness in some cases, notably TS.

Answer (score 0):

`setup` sets up an instance and returns properties that it should have. The purpose of Composition API, which `setup` is a part of, is to replace Options API, where an instance is determined by component options. So `setup` is the replacement for `data`, `methods`, `computed`, `watch` and lifecycle hooks.

As [the reference](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#lifecycle-hooks) explains, `setup` also replaces `beforeCreate` and `created` lifecycle hooks, the rest of hooks are set inside of it.

There is no conflict between data and props in `setup` function because `props` is accessible as `setup` parameter, i.e. `warning` and `props.warning` are accessible at the same time. In a template, they aren't and shouldn't be distinguished, they instance properties, the solution is to not allow name conflicts. They have been previously available with `$data.warning` and `$props.warning` magic keywords but their use wasn't encouraged. If `warning` value differs from a prop of the same name, and both should be available in a template, it should have a different name.